# Can not get selected rows on datatable jquery

Tags: jquery, html, thymeleaf

This is my table:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover table-sm table-bordered "
       id="deposit-files-table">
```

This is script file:

```
<script>
var logsTable ;
      $(document).ready(function () {
                 // logsTable = $('#deposit-files-table').DataTable();
                logsTable = $('#deposit-files-table').DataTable();
                var submitPasswordChangeButton = document.getElementById("xx");
            });


            $('#deposit-files-table tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {

                $(this).toggleClass('selected');// i can see my row here from console debug
                debugger;
                var logsTable = $('#deposit-files-table').DataTable();//i have to redefinde this, but i already defined in ready function?
                var rowdata = logsTable.rows('.selected').data();//this brings only current
     //$('#deposit-files-table').DataTable().rows('.selected').data() also this bring current selected
            } );
```

I also defined a button and when clicked, i wanted to get all selected rows with same codes but it brings empty.

Comment: Possible off topic: "*already defined in ready function?*" - no, each variable has "scope" (in javascript it's not quite as simple as inside each `{}` is a different scope, but think of it that way and you'll be fine).

Comment: Depends on where the button is in relation to the table.  Or you can access them directly `$("#deposit-files-table tr.selected")`

Comment: @freedomn-m `$("#deposit-files-table tr.selected")` works. Can I use it with var, like `logsTable.$("tr.selected").length`

Comment: Yes, but use `.find` - `var tbl = $("#deposite-files-table");  tbl.find("tr.selected")`

Comment: @freedomn-m it says `tbl.find is not a function` for `tbl.find("tr.selected")`

Comment: Then `tbl` is not a jquery object - if you're using `logsTable` from your code, then that's a datatable object.  `var tbl = $("#deposit-files-table");` (nothing after this, no `.DataTable()`)

Comment: @freedomn-m i did this: `$('#deposit-files-table tbody').on('click', 'tr', function() {
                $(this).toggleClass('selected');
          
                var tbl = $("#deposite-files-table");
                console.log(tbl.find("tr.selected").toArray());
            });` but array is empty or console result

Comment: Looks like you copied my typo - you do need to look at what you're doing, don't just blindly copy.  Also, `.toArray` is appropriate there - you wanted "*to get all selected rows*" - if you want the IDs or something from those rows, then you need `.map`.